# After I type the letter and then erase all, the words in the boxes shouldn't shown any color

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .red{
     color : red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="search"/>    
      <table id="boxdata">
                <tr>
              <td class="namebox1">claim</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="namebox2">plane</td>
            </tr>
       </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#search').keyup(function(){ 
        searchBox($(this).val());
       });
    });

    function searchBox(inputStr) {
      $('#boxdata').find('tr').each(function(index, row){
        var names = $(row).find('td');
          if(names.length > 0) { 
          var found = false;
           names.each(function(index, td) {
             var regExp = new RegExp(inputStr, 'gi');
           if(regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                 found = true;
             return false;
           }
              if($("input[type=text]").val() == ''){

              }
           });

             if(found == true)
              $(row).addClass("red");
             else 
              $(row).removeClass();        
          }
      });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

After I type the letter on the textfields and erase all, the words in the boxes shouldn't shown any color. 
but my code is showing red color on all words constantly.
please tell me where to change my code.

Comment: The question is not clear...

Comment: for example, if i type the letter 'c' on the textfields. then the word 'claim' font color must be changed black to red. and also if i type the letter 'p'. then the word 'plane' must be changed. would it be enough you to understand? and i ommited some css code. it wouldnt matter to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that empty text satisfies your regex check as both "plane" and "claim" do contain the text "".

In you searchBox function change your if check to also check inputStr is not empty

```
function searchBox(inputStr) {
    var box = $('#boxdata');
    box.find('tr').each(function(index, row){
        var names = $(row).find('td');
        if(names.length > 0) { 
            var found = false;
            names.each(function(index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputStr, "gi");
                console.log(inputStr);
                if(regExp.test($(td).text()) && inputStr != "") {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if(found == true){
                $(row).addClass("red");   
            }
            else {
                $(row).removeClass();        
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that, empty string matched both words, since RegExp passed them both.

I suppose this should work in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function(){ 
        searchBox($(this).val());
    });
});

function searchBox(inputStr) {
    var box = $('#boxdata');
    box.find('tr').each(function(index, row){
        var names = $(row).find('td');
        if(names.length > 0) { 
            var found = false;
            names.each(function(index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputStr, 'gi');
                if(regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                }
                if($("input").val().length == 0){
                    found=false;
                }
            });          
            if(found) {
                $(row).addClass("red");
            }
            else {
                $(row).removeClass("red");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AeGzC/1/)**